# Spring Kafka Binder not receiving any messages but is connected to the topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Hello I have been using Spring Kafka Binder as a consumer. Looking through the logs, I am able to connect to the topic although I am not sure why it is not processing any messages from the producer.

Any idea on what may be missing? Thank you!

**POM**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Application YML**

```
cloud:
zookeeper:
  connect-string: port1.test.com:2181,port2.test.com:2181,port3.test.com:2181
stream:
  kafka:
    binder:
      brokers:
        - port1.test.com:6667
        - port2.test.com:6667
        - port3.test.com:6667
      auto-create-topics: false
      auto-add-partitions: false
      jaas:
        controlFlag: REQUIRED
        loginModule: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
        options:
          useKeyTab: true
          storeKey: true
          serviceName: kafka
          # Change location to your local location
          keyTab: C:\\Users\\src\\main\\resources\\kafka\\kafka_user.keytab
          principal: kafka_user@TEST.COM
          debug: true
      configuration:
        security:
          protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
  bindings:
    stream-input:
      binder: kafka
      destination: TOPIC
      group: service-dev
security:
  krb5conf:
    # Change location to your local location
    location: C:\\Users\\src\\main\\resources\\kafka\\krb5nonprod.conf
```

**Consumer class**

```
public interface EventConsumer {

@Input("stream-input")
SubscribableChannel consumeMessage();
}
```

**Listener class**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableBinding(EventConsumer.class)
public class EventListener {

@StreamListener(target = "stream-input")
public void processMessage(Object msg) {
```

**Logs**

```
Started Application in 75.471 seconds (JVM running for 184.663)
2021-09-29 19:45:01.342  INFO 30340 --- [container-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        
: [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=service-dev] Cluster ID: qa_IFa70SravzxvdcDhHA
2021-09-29 19:45:01.390  INFO 30340 --- [container-0-C-1] 
o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=service-dev] 
Discovered group coordinator port1.test.com:6667 (id: 2147482644 rack: null)
2021-09-29 19:45:01.399  INFO 30340 --- [container-0-C-1] 
o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=service-dev] 
Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2021-09-29 19:45:01.400  INFO 30340 --- [container-0-C-1] 
o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1  : service-dev: partitions revoked: []
2021-09-29 19:45:01.401  INFO 30340 --- [container-0-C-1] 
o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=service-dev] 
(Re-)joining group
2021-09-29 19:45:01.854  INFO 30340 --- [container-0-C-1] 
o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=service-dev] 
(Re-)joining group
2021-09-29 19:45:04.387  INFO 30340 --- [container-0-C-1] 
o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=service-dev] 
Successfully joined group with generation 36
2021-09-29 19:45:04.400  INFO 30340 --- [container-0-C-1] 
o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=service-dev] 
Setting newly assigned partitions: TOPIC-0
2021-09-29 19:45:04.481  INFO 30340 --- [container-0-C-1] 
o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=service-dev] 
Setting offset for partition TOPIC-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1076, 
offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=port1.test.com:6667 (id: 1003 
rack: /default-rack), epoch=2}}
2021-09-29 19:45:04.557  INFO 30340 --- [container-0-C-1] 
o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1  : service-dev: partitions assigned: [TOPIC-0]
```

As you can see from the logs, it was able to connect to the topic. Although I am not sure why I am not receiving any messages from the producer. Is it because of the revoking of the partitions? Does it have something to do on why I am not receiving any messages? The producer comes from a 3rd party, does he needs to do something in order for me to receive messages? It is clear that I am able to connect to the topic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Log looks good; it implies there are no more records to read after the current committed offset for this group

```
>Setting offset for partition TOPIC-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1076 ...
```

If you want to re-read the entire topic you can set the resetOffsets kafka consumer binding property, or change the `group` to one that doesn't have a committed offset.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#reset-offsets

Comment: Thanks for your comment? 
   "it implies there are no more records to read after the current committed offset for this 
   group"
Does that mean that there are no messages from the consumer?

Comment: It means that a consumer with group.id `service-dev` has previously read 1076 records from the topic and this instance is waiting for new ones, starting with that offset.

Comment: Thank you so much! So it means that it was able to read/get data from the producer. Im just curious why it is not continuing or undergoing the EventListener class (processMessage method)?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean; when this consumer was started, Kafka determined that the consumer had PREVIOUSLY read all the records in the topic and it is now waiting for more. If you publish additional records to the topic, the consumer will receive them.

Comment: I have a listener class, which gets the message and processes it. Im not sure why upon checking the logs, there isn't anything about processing the messages. Below is my Listener class:

Comment: @/Slf4j
@/Component
@/RequiredArgsConstructor
@/EnableBinding(EventConsumer.class)
public class EventListener {

@StreamListener(target = "stream-input")
public void processMessage(Object msg) {
--- process message ----
}

Comment: I see you are new here - don't put code in comments; it doesn't render well; in any case, you already added that to the question. As I said, it won't see any more records until either you reset the committed offset, change the group, or publish some more records.

Comment: yes sir, im new here :) Thank you for this! Im gonna check this. Thanks!